# Drawing a graph for the tempreture sensor with sense hat and matplotlib module

Tags: python, list, loops, matplotlib, valueerror

I am a little bit stuck on a project that I want to complete if someone could help me it would be great, the project is creating a graph for the sense hat temperature sensor with matplotlib.

What I can do is create a graph with the following code;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
plt.plot([], [], 'b-')#Plots go inside the square brackets

plt.axis([0, 24, -5, 30])
plt.ylabel('Tempreture')#Label of the Y axis 'ylabel'
plt.xlabel('Time (Hours)')#Label of the X axis 'xlabel'

plt.show()#Displays the graph
```

And I can also collect a large range of tempreture with this simple loop;

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat

temperature = []
while True:
    temp = sense.get_temperature()
    temp1 = round(temp, 2)
    temperature.append(temp1)
```

But my problem is putting these two pieces of code together as I have tried to insert my list tempreture unto the y axis however it came up with the error

```
ValueError: x and y must have the same first dimension
```

so if anyone could help me to create a graph for my sense hat tempreture sensor I would be greatful.

Comment: A plot needs x and y values. If you only provide y values, they won't have any x partner.

Comment: I had my tempreture list in the x position and then the numbers 0 to 24 to represent the 24 hours in a day